# Memory leak when using std::list

Tags: c++, stdlist

How to remove memory leak from `std::list`?

This is just example code :

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    list<int> a;
    a.clear();
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

When I try to run it, it shows some memory leak.

So, how to remove it?

Comment: I would recomment just doing `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );` at the beginning of your program, so that the memory leak report is generated automatically after your program has run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is likely no memory leak. What the report is telling you is that the memory has not yet been deallocated, which is true. It will be deallocated at the end of the current scope - after the `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` has run.

Alter the code as follows; it will provide you with a more accurate answer:

```
void main()
{
    {
        list<int> a;
        a.clear();
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Note the movement of the `a` container to its own scope.